# How can I disable animation in ImageEx (windows-community-toolkit)

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

How can I disable animation in windows community toolkit's `ImageEx`? Ideally I would like to have the animation only when moving from placeholder image to real image. And if the real image is already there I would like to display it without delay and animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the style from [base style](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/ImageEx/ImageEx.xaml) in the GitHub repo and modify or remove any of the storyboards you don't want for the different transition states. It's fairly easy to remove the animation in this fashion. I don't know if there's a good set of states made available to still keep a transition animation between them.

I know we do want to better optimize this control in the future, so will be good to keep these customizations in mind for that. If you find you need more info from the base control to manage this, please feel free to open an issue on our [GitHub repo](https://aka.ms/windowstoolkit), thanks!

Comment: After using this control in production, the general user expectation is that the Loading state represents the _download_ process however the images that are retrieved from cache come back very fast, so they should appear in the UI faster, The current transition animation makes it look like the cache is just as slow as the remote image. Has anyone figured out a good alternate style for this?